# C++ class member that requires a constructor parameter

Tags: c++

I'm getting confused:

**Director.cpp**

```
class Director {

  public:
  Director() {

  }

  runScene(Scene _scene) {
    scene = _scene;
  }

  private:
  Scene scene; // <-- Private member "scene" of type Scene.

};
```

**Scene.cpp**

```
class Scene {

  public:
  Scene(int number) {


  }

}
```

g++ says

> no matching function for call to 'Scene::Scene()'

It seems like it is trying to initialise `scene`, which can't be done because there are no constructors that take no parameters. I'm still new to C++ - why is it trying to initialise that private member?

I'm not sure what is going on. I tried changing `Scene scene;` to `Scene scene(int);`, which will just cause `runScene` to throw an error, because that would make the compiler think that `scene` is actually a function.

All I want is my class to have a member property of type `Scene`, which I can change at any time. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There are tons of duplicates. Basically, use the constructor initialization list:  Director() : scene(42) {}

Comment: Simplest solution would just be to declare `Scene() {}` in the `public` section of `class Scene`, however, the proper solution might be vastly different and will be dependent on what exactly is the meaning of the `Scene` class and what semantics the `scene` member will be

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By declaring constructor in `Scerne`

```
Scene(int number) {

}
```

you are effectively disabling the default constructor which takes no parameters. You either need to add `Scene()` (No parameters) constructor to your scene class or your `Director` constructor needs to look something like this:

```
Director() : Scene(0)
{
}
```

Comment: No, you are calling constructor of `Scene` which has to has exactly same name as the class it belongs to - so it is `Scene(0)` indeed.